# Python CSV decimal separator

Tags: python, csv

With Python, how can I select decimal separator for CSV files? 
In Python float, decimal separator is point, but for my case comma is needed.

According to [Dialects and Formatting Parameters](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params), there are no parameter in Dialect for this.

I think, problem may be solved with replacing point with comma like this:

```py
str(my_float).replace('.',',')
```

But is seems a very ugly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your floating point numbers double quoted as required? **EDIT**: If they are, you should be able to retrieve each line and rely on [localization](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) to convert the numbers for you.

Comment: @Nasha, yes, it is:

`"2015";"1";"39.68368";"0.0"`